# Cannot Make Mkvmerge to work on all subfolders

Tags: mkv

I am a newbie with `mkvmerge` batch files.

Recently I tried to write a batch file to convert ALL `*.flv` to `*.mkv` to root and then to all subfolders under it. I googled and managed to come up with this batch file which I copy and change some code. It works only if you place `mkvmerge.exe` in all the subfolders that you need to change.

The content of the batch file:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set mkvmerge="D:\mkvmerge.exe"

for /d /r %%D in (*) do (
    pushd %%D

set files=

for %%A IN (*.flv) do ( mkvmerge.exe -o "remux-%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A") 

if not "!files!"=="" %mkvmerge% -o "output.mkv" !files:~2!

popd
)
pause
```

**Question 1:**
How to point the path to mkvmerge.exe so it will work correctly?

**Question 2:**
How to remove the word "remux" from the the converted mkv files? 
I think it something on this line
`( mkvmerge.exe -o "remux-%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A")`, but just don't know how to do it.

**Update:** Disregard Question 2, I managed to do it by replacing it with `( mkvmerge.exe -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A")`

Please help me with Question 1.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to Bother, I solved it
Just Copy mkvmerge.exe to C:\ (Root folder) and in the batch file point to it

Complete working batch file

---

@echo off

for /d /r %%D in (*) do (
    pushd %%D

set files=

for %%A IN (*.flv) do ( c:\mkvmerge.exe -o "%%~nA.mkv" "%%~A")

if not "!files!"=="" %mkvmerge% -o "output.mkv" !files:~2!
popd
)

pause

---